# SDK layoutlib version is not supported in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

This is my problem with Eclipse:

> SDK layoutlib version is not supported

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

What is the solution to this problem? This problem occurs with every API.

Comment: Hello, I strongly recommand you to have a look to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You shouldn't be using Eclipse to develop for Android, Android support for Eclipse [ended in 2016](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html)

Comment: I guess the solution is to stop using Eclipse and start using Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Support for Android development within Eclipse ended in 2016, from the [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html):

> With the release of Android Studio 2.2, the time has now come to say goodbye to the Eclipse Android Developer Tools. We have formally ended their support and development. There's never been a better time to switch to Android Studio and experience the improvements we've made to the Android development workflow.

Android API 28 was released on 6th August 2018 [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history), nearly 2 years after that end-of-life post was made. Therefore it would make sense that the API 28 layout SDKs for the Eclipse plugin were not implemented.

Your best solution would be to migrate your project to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studioW) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with that by changing the API from 28 to 4.0 Since that was what I was developing. I am very new to android dev

SDK Layout version is not supported error - resolved[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8LD8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by changing the API from 28 to 15